# JAXB: Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT works not perfectly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to write an Object to xml with JAXB Marshaller, the content is good, how ever for some element, the formatting is not perfect. I have set the property `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true)` already.

the result is look like following(tsi:mmt part is not indent correctly):

```
<TransportFrame>
    <ServiceData>
        <SID>
            <tdt:SID_A>1</tdt:SID_A>
            <tdt:SID_B>1</tdt:SID_B>
            <tdt:SID_C>1</tdt:SID_C>
        </SID>
        <ServiceComponentMultiplex>
            <ServiceComponent applicationId="0" contentId="0" majorApplicationVersion="3" minorApplicationVersion="2" encId="0" safetyFlag="false">
                <ServiceComponentFrameContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ServCompFrameCountedProtected">
                    <SCID>0</SCID>
                    <MessageCount>8</MessageCount>
                    <ApplicationRootMessage>
                        <ApplicationRootMessageML xsi:type="tsi:TSIMessage">
<tsi:mmt>
<mmt:messageID>1</mmt:messageID>
<mmt:versionID>1</mmt:versionID>
<mmt:messageExpiryTime>2017-01-19T13:13:14.637+01:00</mmt:messageExpiryTime>
<mmt:cancelFlag>false</mmt:cancelFlag>
</tsi:mmt>
                        </ApplicationRootMessageML>
                    </ApplicationRootMessage>
                </ServiceComponentFrameContent>
            </ServiceComponent>
        </ServiceComponentMultiplex>
    </ServiceData>
</TransportFrame>
```

Following it my code, anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

```
Marshaller marshaller = contextObj.createMarshaller();  
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
marshaller.marshal(document, new FileOutputStream(selectedFile));
```

Comment: by the way, the corresponding java class of ApplicationRootMessageML is an abstract class.